# How to submit form to specific method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I need to submit a form to a specific Method from my Controller.
How can I do this?
My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag({update_holidays_path, method: 'post'},{name: "exchange", id: "exchange"}) do %>
<table width="auto" border="0">
  <thead>
    <th  scope="col">Selected</th>
    <th width="50" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th  scope="col">Holidays</th>
  </thead>  
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>  
    <% holidays_array = @group.holidays.all.map { |holiday| [holiday.name, holiday.id] } %>
    <%= select(:holiday_id, :name, options_for_select(holidays_array),{}, 
    {:multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px; background-color: #9FE", :width => "300", :size => 20, :id=>"left" }  ) %>
  </td>
  <td align="center">
      <%= link_to "<<", {anchor: "", remote: true}, {id: "toleft" ,  w_command: "add_holiday", w_auth: form_authenticity_token , w_controller: "groups",  w_id: @group.id} %>
      <br /><br />
      <%= link_to ">>", {anchor: "", remote: true}, {id: "toright" , w_command: "rem_holiday", w_auth: form_authenticity_token , w_controller: "groups",  w_id: @group.id} %>
  </td>    
  <td>
    <% holidays_array = Holiday.all.map { |holiday| [holiday.name, holiday.id] } %>
    <%= select(:holiday_id, :name,  options_for_select(holidays_array),{}, 
    { :multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px; background-color: #F99", :width => "300", :size => 20, :id=>"right" } ) %>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to submit my left select with the following javascript:

```
var save=function()
{
alert("0");
var left = document.getElementById("left");
alert(left);
var result = document.exchange;
alert(result);
result= ""
alert("3");
for(i=0;i<right.length;i++)
    {       
    result.value=result.value+","+left.options[i].value; //right.options[i].selected = true;
    alert("4,"+i+"    "+result.value);
    }
alert("5");          
result.submit();
}
```

Is there a way do do this?

Answer (score 2):

change `update_holidays_path` to the path of the controller & action you want to call.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal. go to your rails_app_root directory and do `rake routes`
This will give you the list of all available paths

For example:

```
 cases GET    /cases(.:format)                                    cases#index
```

Here the `cases#index` indicates that the `cases` is controller name and `index` is the method
so when you write `cases_path` it will generate path for this controller and action

So find out matching route for your controller and action in list of `rake routes`, and then select the left most text and append `_path` after it(just like I have showed in above example) and then replace the `update_holidays_path` in below line with this new found path.

`<%= form_tag({update_holidays_path, method: 'post'},{name: "exchange", id: "exchange"}) do %>`

**EDIT**

And if the path is not present in `rake routes` list then you need to add this path in your `routes.rb` file.